# Scrabble Word Generator (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, list, flash

This is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var loadTxt:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loadTxt.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var wordList:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    trace("> " + wordList)
}

loadTxt.load(new URLRequest("list.txt"));

btnSolve.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, solve)

function solve(Event:MouseEvent){
    var wordString = this.wordTxt.text
    var wordArray:Array = wordString.split("");
    trace("> " + wordArray);
}
```

I want check the letters in the input against the word list, and put all the words that the letters can spell in a list. Right now I just want to know how I can check if the letters can spell something in the word list.

Answer (score 0):

[John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) (of jQuery and Khan Academy fame) has a couple of blog posts about this sort of thing.

He investigates the use of the [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to represent and lookup the words efficiently - the code is in JavaScript but that's very easy to convert to Actionscript.

- http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/
- http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/
- http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/

There is obviously some complexity to this sort of problem so you'll have to work out what the best approach is to your situation. Good luck!

Comment: I am trying make a Scrabble solver, not a checker. The links you gave me were about checking for a word in a list, which was not what I was looking for.

Comment: "I want check the letters in the input against the word list, and put all the words that the letters can spell in a list." It's the same problem space. Once you've got a good representation of your words and a way to check them easily (i.e. a Trie) then you can work out the appropriate algorithm for testing all combinations of characters. The simplest approach is test all combinations of 7 letters (approx. 5040 combinations) but not all combinations will be valid so the actual number of comparisons will be less than that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a [GADDAG](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADDAG) to efficiently store and walk all permutations of a tile set. I don't know of an pre-existing implementation of one in as3 but here are some supporting documentation:

[Formal Description](http://www.ericsink.com/downloads/faster-scrabble-gordon.pdf)

[.net implementation](http://nullwords.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/gaddag-data-structure/)

[optimization](http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/87682811573/compressing-scrabble-dictionaries)